# Converting bitwise AND/NOT from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Original code (VB.NET):

```
curStyle = curStyle And (Not ES_NUMBER)
```

Changed code (C#):

```
curStyle = curStyle & (!ES_NUMBER);
```

But it is giving me this error:

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'long'

ES_NUMBER is of data type long. I tried changing it to int, string, etc. All doesn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Get Reflector. It will show you this and many other translations.

Comment: `~` is the bitwise complement operator, which flips every bit in the operand.

Answer (score 9):

`And` is the same as `&`; you got that correctly. `Not` in front of a `Long` is a bitwise NOT operator. The C# equivalent is `~`.

The C# code would be:

```
curStyle = curStyle & (­~ES_NUMBER);
```

Check out *[Bitwise operators in c# OR(|), XOR(^), AND(&), NOT(~)](http://blog.typps.com/2007/10/bitwise-operators-in-c-or-xor-and-not.html)* , explaining C# bitwise operators.

Comment: You could also write `curStyle &= ~ES_NUMBER;`.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, a trip to the documentation proves instructional:

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx):

> The logical negation operator (!) ... is defined for bool and returns true if and only if its operand is false.

There is nothing in the documentation anywhere about any behavior at all for numeric expressions, which I would expect mean that the operator is not defined to work with those expressions at all.

On the other hand, [MSDN has this to say about VB.NET's Not operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx):

> For numeric expressions, the Not operator inverts the bit values of any numeric expression and sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table...

So the question is now: How to reproduce the behavior of VB.NET's "Not" for C#? Thankfully, it's not hard: you can use the [~ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx).

```
curStyle = curStyle & (­~ES_NUMBER);
```

And, just for good measure, the [documentation on &](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

> For integral types, & computes the bitwise AND of its operands.

Answer (score 0):

A single ampersand is usually a bit-wise operation, but the exclamation is a logical operation. You need to use [two ampersands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) a la [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) if you want a logical AND:

```
curStyle = curStyle && (!ES_NUMBER);
```

Or a tilde if you want a bit-wise AND:

```
curStyle = curStyle & (~ES_NUMBER);
```

Comment: A single ampersand is not always a bit-wise and. Consider (true & false) which is a logical and.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, I just looked up the `And` and `Not` keywords in VB. Interesting that they work implicitly.

Comment: Back when VB 7 was in beta (i.e. VB.NET) there was huge arguments about whether to keep it that way or to create explicit BitAnd, BitOr, and BitNot operators.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: Implicitly seems like it would work ok though. I quite like it.

Answer (score 0):

The key question is (and the answer to which is not provided): Is `curStyle` an integer or a bool? Are you trying to get a truth value (bool, true/false), or are you trying to mask out bits in a bit field?

For the former case, where `curStyle` is a bool (truth value), you say:

```
curStyle = curStyle && !ES_NUMBER ;
```

The latter case, where `curStyle` is an integer type and  you want to manipulate its bits, takes:

```
curStyle = curStyle & ~Not ES_NUMBER ;
```

Comment: ES_NUMBER is a long. Therefore (Not ES_NUMBER) is a long. Which in turn means curStyle must be a long if using strict type checking.